# Dismiss A Custom Dialog on Click of Button in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog .So a button click i am showing it .Now i have a button in the custom dialog i want to close it on click of that button but it is throwing any null pointer exception.Here is my code that i am using to show it:

```
private void showPreConfirmationDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context);;
    button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pre_confirmation_dailog);
            //dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setTitle("OnWard Details...");
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);
    backPreConfirmation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}
```

On click of backPreConfirmation button it is throwing my this error :

```
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.result/com.android.result.Result}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at com.android.result.Result.showPreConfirmationDialog(Result.java:66)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at com.android.result.Result.onCreate(Result.java:41)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-30 09:25:15.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26599):    ... 11 more
```

What i have wrong please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dialog object to initialize your views

```
  final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pre_confirmation_dailog);
  backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);
```

Initialize this in `onCreate`

```
 button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
```

Then

```
 button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
 {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       showPreConfirmationDialog();
    }
 });
```

In showPreConfirmationDialog()

```
private void showPreConfirmationDialog() {
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pre_confirmation_dailog);  
dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
dialog.show(); 
backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);
backPreConfirmation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
});
}
```

Note :  You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. You set the content of your layout to dialog. And you have button `backPreConfirmation` in that layout. So you need to use the dialog object to inflate your button.

Comment: I done the same changes still the same issue .same error in the error log

Comment: button  is in the main layout and backPreConfirmation  in the preconformation dialog layout

Comment: @Gaurav initialize the button in main layout in `onCreate`. then on click of that button display the dialog.

Comment: @Gaurav you are welcome always remember you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change for both like this:

```
button = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);
```

So,now you can get proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its because "backPreConfirmation" is not inside your main layout.It is inside your "`pre_confirmation_dailog`" layout. To get this method do the following,

```
replace
  backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backImage);
with

  backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
button = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
```

this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting reference of current activity view to dialog's child, instead of this use dialog for setting up reference to all dialog child `button = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
        backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);`

Answer (score 0):

private void showPreConfirmationDialog() {

```
    button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bookButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

               final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context);
          dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);// Custome layout xml 
            dialog.setTitle("OnWard Details...");
    backPreConfirmation = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.backImage);   
    backPreConfirmation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

}
```

> try this

Answer (score 0):

try this.
...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
             dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
dialog.show();
```

...

Comment: Try adding a bit more description about why you've answered this way.  Please read the guidelines for answering questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

the solution above works but it is a bit long, I guess the best solution is to make the Dialog object global or field of the activity you are working at, then when you finish working with it, use the method dismiss() on the object.

```
//out side any method(global domain)
private Dialog dialog;

//inside the button handler of the dialog
dialog.dismiss();
```